# Bootstrap modal works in static webpage, but not in React.js equivalent

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap, react-modal

I'm building a site from a Bootstrap template that comes with some modal components, specifically in the 'portfolio' section of [this template](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/freelancer). The modals work fine when my page is entirely front end. But when I copy and paste the page out of index.html and into a React component to mount, nothing happens upon clicking upon any modal trigger.

There are no errors or warnings. Is there a simple explanation for what I'm missing for why the page isn't behaving the same? Thanks in advance.